# ¿Cómo se llama la aversión al número 88?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, palabras-raras, neologismos, psicología

Para esta pregunta me viene de perlas que hoy sea día trece, aunque habría sido mejor martes y trece, o viernes trece. Veréis, la *triscaidecafobia* (no la busquéis en el DRAE que no viene) es el miedo irracional al número 13.

> La **triscaidecafobia** (del griego τρεισκαιδέκα, *treiskaideka*, «trece» junto con φοβία, *fobía*, «miedo») es el miedo irracional al número 13. Se considera normalmente una superstición. La fobia específica al viernes 13 se llama *parascevedecatriafobia* (la *Parasceve* es la preparación de la Pascua), *collafobia*, o bien *friggatriscaidecafobia* (la palabra *Friday*, "viernes" en inglés, procede del nombre de la diosa vikinga Frigga). El miedo al martes 13 se llama *trezidavomartiofobia*.
>
> Fuente: [*triscaidecafobia* en Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triscaidecafobia)

El artículo cita algunos posibles orígenes para tal superstición y complementa el artículo con fobias similares:

- La **tetrafobia** es el miedo al número 4 (la palabra japonesa shi (死) quiere decir muerte, y se pronuncia igual que el 4)
- la **hexakosioihexekontahexafobia** es el miedo irracional al "666", el "número de la bestia", ligado al Anticristo.

En Italia el número de la mala suerte es el 17. Esto se debe a que el 17, en números romanos, se escribe XVII. Reordenando sus letras podemos escribir VIXI, que en latín significa "viví", es decir, "mi vida es pasado".

Todo esto está extraído de ese enlace de Wikipedia, pero es corroborable en otros sitios.

El 88 (ochenta y ocho) es otro de esos números *chungos*. Si a cada letra del abecedario se le asigna un número, empezando por la A, el número 88 equivaldrá a "HH" (código muy utilizado por los seguidores del nazismo, que significa "Heil Hitler!").

Esta aversión es menos extendida. Sin embargo, como os podéis imaginar, personas que han nacido en 1988 tienden a favorecer esa pareja de números al crear alias para internet. Por ejemplo, Fulano88@gmail.com o Menganito88 como alias/nick en un sitio de internet. Luego, hay gente que les reprocha su (inexistente) respaldo, apoyo o adherencia al nazismo, pensando que ese 88 significa algo que no es, y claro: estos pobres usuarios flipan de que sin venir a cuento les tachen de nazis.

Mi pregunta es: de manera análoga a lo que ocurre con el 13, 4 y 666, ¿cómo se llama la aversión al número 88?

Comment: en la cultura china se trata de un número de suerte. Quizá por eso tambien se ve en todos lados.

Answer (score 3):

A la vista de los ejemplos, la norma para formar este tipo de neologismos parece ser: número en griego + *-fobia*.

[Según el traductor de Google](https://translate.google.com/#es/el/ochenta%20y%20ocho), "ochenta y ocho" en griego se dice *ogdónta októ* (ογδόντα οκτώ).

Por tanto, la palabra (técnica) para designar el miedo al número 88 podría ser ***ogdontaoctofobia***.

Simplificando un poco la pronunciación, podríamos usar *ogdontoctofobia*, *odontaoctofobia* u *odontoctofobia*, aunque el prefijo "odonto-" de las dos últimas opciones suele estar relacionado con los dientes así que no me convence mucho.

Comment: Para evitar lo impronunciable de **_ogdontaoctofobia_** y la posible confusión con "algo de los los dientes" de la versión con **_odonto_**,  quizás se podría utilizar la versión latina de ochenta y ocho (octoginta octo) y crear la **_octogintaoctofobia_**

Comment: Por lo visto un polígono de 88 lados es un *Octacontakaioctágonos* así que supongo que podríamos decir: **Octacontakaioctofobia**

Comment: @JamesBolivar y blonfu, si bien es cierto que vuestros comentarios están bien usados para aclarar y mejorar la respuesta de walen, también podrían ser respuestas propias Tienen enfoques ligeramente distintos (usar el latín en lugar del griego; usar palabras existentes en otras "industrias") por lo que podrían ser respuestas por derecho propio. Así el resto de usuarios podrían valorar `octogintaoctofobia` y `Octacontakaioctofobia` de manera independiente al `ogdontaoctofobia` de walen (y aparte tendría el efecto secundario de mejorar nuestras estadísticas para número de respuestas por pregunta)

Comment: es mas miedo al ocho-ocho que al ochenta y ocho

Comment: @Mike, Bueno, no realmente "miedo", pero yo usaría "fobia" igualmente para construir esta palabra. Aunque sí me refería a un "miedo" o fobia para la triscaidecafobia, tetrafobia y hexakosioihexekontahexafobia, en este caso más que miedo es una adversión o repulsa. Alguien querría evitar el 13 por superstición o miedo, mientras que para el 88 es más bien odio o rechazo. En cualquier caso, tus apuntes son más que válidos y te digo lo mismo que a walen y james, por si quieres aportar algo como duo-octo-fobia como respuesta propia.

Comment: @Mike: o **_octooctofobia_** para fonia al ocho-ocho

Comment: @Diego, lo he puesto en la respuesta de walen como comentario porque mi aportación en realidad es lo mismo que ha dicho él, solo que ha buscado la palabra en griego y ha hecho una adaptación y yo he buscado una palabra similar que ya existe y he usado ese prefijo para crear la palabra.

Comment: @Diego: simplemente poner la alternativa basada en latín en vez de en griego no me parece que sea suficiente como para una respuesta. Yo lo veo (y por eso lo he puesto así) como un simple comentario, por si a walen le parece adecuado añadirlo o comentarlo en su respuesta.

Comment: Si me acuerdo a la tarde  haré una respuesta con lo mio

Answer (score 2):

Siguiendo el razonamiento de @walen parece que lo normal es usar la palabra en griego y añadirle *fobia* para definir aversiones o miedos.

Se me ocurrió buscar entonces el nombre de un polígono de 88 lados y encontré que se llamaba *octacontakaioctágonos*, en estos dos blogs: [lascosasdematematicas.blogspot.com.es](http://lascosasdematematicas.blogspot.com.es/2017/11/formula-maximo-comun-divisor.html) y [matekas.blogspot.com.es](http://matekas.blogspot.com.es/2008/06/nombre-de-los-polgonos-iii.h%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Btml). No he podido encontrar alguna fuente más fiable ya que la mayoría de las listas de este tipo llegan hasta los polígonos de 20 lados y luego van de diez en diez.

Supongo que aunque no esté definido en ningún sitio la aversión al número 88 podría llamarse **Octacontakaioctofobia** 
siguiendo la misma lógica.

Comment: ¿Dónde has encontrado octacontakaioctágono?

Comment: Aquí: http://lascosasdematematicas.blogspot.com.es/ o aquí: http://matekas.blogspot.com.es/2008/06/nombre-de-los-polgonos-iii.html. Aunque no aparece en muchos más sitios, normalmente en las listas aparecen hasta el 30 y luego van de diez en diez.

Comment: Perfecto, no lo había localizado con SanGoogle. Quizás podrías considerar incluir en enlace en tu respuesta, para completarla ?

Answer (score 0):

The particular example which is involved here does not seem to me to be a phobia in the normal sense of the word. If we consult Wikipedia we find:

> Una fobia (palabra derivada de Fobos, en griego antiguo Φόϐος, «pánico», hijo de Ares y Afrodita en la mitología griega, la personificación del miedo) es un trastorno de salud emocional o psicológico que se caracteriza por un miedo intenso y desproporcionado ante objetos o situaciones concretas​ como, por ejemplo, a los insectos (entomofobia) o a los lugares cerrados (claustrofobia). Sin embargo, no es sencillamente un miedo, pues guardan grandes diferencias.

To experience a phobia you must have fear and it must be disproportionate. For it to reach clinical significance it must interfere with your daily life too in some way. Some of the quoted numerical examples may amount to phobia (people avoiding situation with 13 by not booking into room 13, insisting on inviting an extra guest to avoid having 13 at table) but the example of 88 does not seem to me like that. We have a situation where people feel it better to avoid something out of a principle just as they would avoid pejorative terms for ethnic groups, sexual orientation, religious symbols, and so on. If we need a word for what people are expressing about 88 would *antinazismo* not be sufficient?

Comment: Mira mi comentario a Mike en la respuesta de Walen. He usado "aversión" a propósito en lugar de "miedo". Creo que "antinazismo" engloba más cosas que esa repudia al número 88, aunque las raíces sean las mismas. Aparte, si alguien ve un 88 y asume siempre que es una referencia al "Heil Hitler", incluso en otros contextos, posiblemente eso sea también un problema psicológico menor. No un fobia, pero si otra cosa. Por ejemplo, si yo pienso que **siempre** me van a robar al salir de casa no soy precavido, si no paranoico. Esta aversión puede ser similar.