# Si tres libros pertenecen a una trilogía, ocho, ¿a qué pertenecen?

Tags: vocabulario, solicitud-de-término, palabras-raras, números, prefijos

Si tres libros pertenecen a una trilogía, ¿cómo se denomina a una serie de ocho libros?

Comment: Una serie de ocho libros.

Comment: Dice [Fundeu a través de twitter](https://twitter.com/fundeu/status/540534798616641537?lang=bg) que "Tanto «nonalogía» como «enealogía» son términos adecuados para referirse a una obra escrita en nueve partes.". Cuando le predunta por la serie de ocho responden que "Solo «octología» [y no 'ochología']" sería válido. Como no he conseguido encontrar el porqué, no lo pongo como respuesta, pero espero que alguien pueda ampliar.

Comment: @Diego, es cierto un neologismo así sería paralelo al término inglés `octology`. Hice una referencia en la respuesta

Comment: Aunque _octologia_ parece ser la respuesta correcta, prefiero utilizar _antología_

Comment: Lo que importa es si alguien lo dice, y no que exista. Entiendo octology pero nunca lo he visto utilizado por ningun autor.

Answer (score 6):

Dice [Fundéu a través de Twitter](https://twitter.com/fundeu/status/540534798616641537) que:

> Tanto «nonalogía» como «enealogía» son términos adecuados para referirse a una obra escrita en **nueve** partes.

Cuando se les pregunta por la serie de **ocho** responden que sería una **octología** (pero no una *ochología*).

Fundéu no explica por qué ni en ese hilo de Twitter ni en ningún artículo, pero ese prefijo *octo* (ocho) es el mismo que encontramos en términos como el que describen el polígono de ocho lados (octógono) y el poliedro de ocho caras (octaedro u octoedro).

> Un octaedro u octoedro (del griego ὀκτώ "ocho" y ἕδρα "asiento" o "cara") es un poliedro de ocho caras
>
> Fuente: [wikipedia para *octaedro*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octaedro)

Comparando esos prefijos que usamos en la formación de los nombres de polígonos (2D) o poliedros (3D), vemos que las series de libros serían

- De tres un **tri**logía (como **tri**ángulo)
- De cuatro una **tetra**logía (como **tetra**edro)
- De cinco un **penta**logía (como [pentaedro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentaedro), pentagrama, pentágono)

y así sucesivamente. Creo recordar que los poliedros regulares más "famosos" son el tetraedro (4), hexaedro (6), octaedro (8), dodecaedro (12) e icosaedro(20), porque estos era los dados de mis juegos de rol. Así por ejemplo podríamos hablar de una *dodecalogía* o incluso *icosalogía*. Si la serie fuese de diecisiete libros, pues habría que conocer el número en griego para formar el prefijo correspondiente.

Como curiosidad, el miedo al número trece se llama [triscaidecafobia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triscaidecafobia) (del griego τρεισκαιδέκα, treiskaideka: ‘trece’). Una serie de trece libros sería por tanto una *triscaidecalogía*. Existe también la [tetrafobia y la ogdontaoctofobia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23545/5481) (miedo al número 88). Con el traductor incluido en esa respuesta enlazada, puedes generar tus prefijos para cualquier número griego.

Answer (score 3):

Aparentemente —dado que la RAE no registra `octología`, ni pude encontrarla en otros diccionarios de castellano —no habría un término **para una serie de ocho obras** (como si la hay en inglés con el término preciso de [***octalogy***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/octalogy#English))

> **octalogy** (also octology)
>
> (rare) A set of eight works of art that are connected, and that can be seen either as a single work or as eight individual works. They are commonly found in literature, film, or video games.
>
> [*(poco frecuente) Un conjunto de trabajos que están conectados, y pueden verse como una sola pieza u obras independientes. Comúnmente en literatura, cine o video-juegos*]

Vista la definición de [trilogía](https://dle.rae.es/trilog%C3%ADa) como *conjunto* de tres obras, según la Real Academia

> 1. f. Conjunto de tres obras literarias o musicales que tienen entre sí enlace histórico o unidad de protagonismo o intención.
> 2. f. Conjunto de tres obras trágicas de un mismo autor, presentadas a concurso en los festivales teatrales de la Grecia clásica.

Una manera razonable de referirse a esa cantidad, por lo tanto, sería simplemente hacerlo como a **un *[conjunto](https://dle.rae.es/conjunto?m=form)*, *[serie](https://dle.rae.es/serie?m=form)*, *[colección](https://dle.rae.es/colecci%C3%B3n)*, *[selección](https://dle.rae.es/selecci%C3%B3n?m=form)* (o, en algún caso *[antología](https://dle.rae.es/antolog%C3%ADa?m=form)*) de ocho libros**

**PD**: aclaro (basado en una constatación posterior sobre literatura publicada e indexada por [google books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=Octologia)) que existen algunos casos de autores usando **octología**.  La opción acaso sea válida para decidir su uso, dependiendo de la audiencia y de nuestro propio criterio de comunicación.